# No effect after making a symbolic link on OS X El Capitan

Tags: macos, terminal, symlink

I want to make a symbolic link of Sublime to be able to launch it from the terminal by simply typing sub. To do this I tried `ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/sub`But when I type sub in the terminal I get command not found. where is the problem? And yes I have `usr/local/bin` in the `$PATH`

Comment: Didn't you mean type `subl`?

Comment: @trojanfoe I wanted to shorten it to just `sub`

Comment: Yes; I missed that.  It should work.  Try using `subl`.